# Remove a rang of numbers by which regular expression / regex

Tags: xml, regex

I have a `XMLexport` tool (PHP) which exports data to an XML field.

It is possible to find and replace some unnecessary characters. But in this case the characters are not always the same.

E.g.`<xmlfield> {"1596":" maat XL </xmlfield> --> this must be <xmlfield> maat XL </xmlfield>`

So I want to remove `{"1596":"`. Only the numeric code changes, e.g. `{"1595":" {"844":"`.

The solution is "find and replace" with a regular expression, but I don't know which code I have to use.

Please let me known if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression to do that would be: `\{"\d+"\:"` Depending on the tool or programming language you are using you might have to escape the `"` as well. Java also needs to escape the `\` with another `\`.

If you are not familiar with regex, let me explain it shortly:

Some characters like `{` or `:` need to be escaped (therefore we add a `\` before that). `\d` matches any digit (0-9) and the `+` means it has to be at least one digit (but possibly more).

You can use online tools like [RegExPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to create and test your regex.

If you want to find those strings only inside `<xmlfield>` tags (without other nested tags in it) you could use something like this: `<xmlfield>[^<]*\{"\d+"\:"[^<]*</xmlfield>`

Comment: Hello SebastianH, many thanks! This is the solution.
I have used /[^<]*\{"\d+"\:"[^<]*/ and it works perfect.:)

Comment: @user3337430 please accept it as the "correct" answer then. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I use this site when I need to work out regular expressions: [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)

this code will replace what you want though:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{\""\d+\"":\""");
reg.Replace(xmlString, string.Empty);
```